# hybrid app performance specifics

Tags: html, performance, native, hybrid

I have read a number of articles, blogs, forum discussions etc. conveying the opinion or observation that HTML5 based apps become slow and crash prone above a certain complexity threshold. I have not, however, been able to find any specific information on what is meant by "slow" or "complex." At what point does an app become complex enough that it is slower running as a hybrid app than as a native one? What makes an app complex in this sense? Can this be worked around?

My company is in the process of deciding between native or hybrid for our first app and it is difficult to determine if the proposed app will be complex enough to rule out hybrid development without a better understanding of what this means, precisely.

Thanks.

Comment: i have nearly the same question...so push! May be you could find here some suggestions..http://phonegap.com/app/

Answer (score 1):

There is no silver bullet to have a benchmark or a threshold of how slow or how complex an application be to decide hybrid or native. In my view, its you and your stake holders that have to define this threshold for app as per your requirements and situations.

There is an excellent blog about it, (I hope the second part of that blog comes soon...) , that tries to answer the above in more strategic point of view, not only just the parameters you have describe but also a range of other aspects, that you have to determine, before you say one or the other.

Article describes the following but you can add or subtract some more.

Leadership
Usability
Performance
Maintainability
Adaptability
Budget
Time to Market
Skills and resources

Following is the link

https://pixyflux.wordpress.com/2015/09/03/how-much-native-binary-vs-spectrum/